# permutation of coefficients that commute with the inversion of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, model-theory

Let $M_n(F)\equiv \mathcal L(F^n) $ be the set of $n\times n$ matrices over a field $F$, and let $\mathbf P\in \mathcal L(M_n(F))$ be a permutation of the canonical basis of $M_n(F)$

Suppose that there exists $A\in GL_n(F)$ such that:

$\mathbf{P}(A^{-1})=(\mathbf{P}(A))^{-1}$

1. Do we necessarily have $\mathbf P(A)= QA P$ for some permutation matrices $P$ and $Q$?
   [note that if $A=I_n$, and $\mathbf P$ is an involution, the fact that $\mathbf P(I_n)$ is in $GL_n(F)$ implies that $\mathbf P(I_n)$ is a permutation matrix]
2. Does the answer to question (1) depend on $F$?

The special case that interests me is when $F=\mathbb F_2$, and $A$ is symmetric, so that one can associate it with some non-oriented graph $G(A)$.

$A^{-1}$  is the co-matrix of $A$  (symmetric in $GL_n(\mathbb F_2)$, so the question could be useful to study the properties of ($n-1$)-sub-graphs of $G(A)$.

Comment: Every permutation which is an involution satisfies your condition, no? Does 1) hold for them?

Comment: Actually... no...I think it is it is not true that  if $\mathbf P$ is an involution, it should satisfy $\mathbf P(A^{-1})= \mathbf P(A)^{-1}$.

Comment: For example take $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\mathbf P(A)= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$. Then $B^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1/2\\ 0 & 1/2\end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathbf P (A^{-1})= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & -2\end{pmatrix}$;

Comment: What do you mean when you use $\mathcal{L}$?

Comment: Model theory? How?

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila : I thought maybe the question 2 would be interesting some model theorists, but I may be out of subject, I hesitated to put this key word anyway...

Comment: @ Amir Sagiv : I meen by $\mathcal L(E)$ the set of linear transformations from $E$ to $E$, I just mentioned it to point the fact that $\mathbf P$ is not a permutation matrix of $\mathcal L(F^n)$ but of $\mathcal L(M_n(F))$ that  dimension is $n^4$.